# How can I calculate total value of actual total field and store this value in another field in model in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

This is the product line model of ORM in Odoo

```py
class productline(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.line'
    
    actual_total = fields.Float(string="Actual Total")
```

XML file for notebook in Odoo where I input actual total field value

```
<notebook>
    <page string="Indent details">
        <field name="roni">
            <tree editable="bottom">
                <!-- Actual total field of the notebook -->
                <field name="actual_total"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Comment: Do you need to add the ``total`` next to the `roni` field?

Comment: I want to find the summation of every line value of the actual_total in another field..

Comment: Where did you define the other field and what is the relation between the two models?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```py
roni = fields.One2many(... 
another_field = fields.Float(string="Actual Total", compute='_compute_total')

@api.depends('roni.actual_total')
def _compute_total(self):
    for record in self:
        record.another_field = sum(record.roni.mapped('actual_total'))
```

```xml
<notebook>
    <page string="Indent details">
        <field name="roni">
            <tree editable="bottom">
                 #actual total field of the notebook
                <field name="actual_total"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
        
        <field name="another_field"/>
    </page>
</notebook>
```